# Inserting SPS, PPS values using ffmpeg for a manifest file

Tags: ffmpeg, gstreamer

I have a bunch of ts segments captured from an RTSP stream coming from an Axis camera which does not have SPS/PPS parameters set.

Because of this I am not able to play the ts segments.

I get the following error when trying to play using ffplay.

```
[NULL @ 0x109813830] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x117f0a360] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x117f0a360] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x117f0a360] no frame!
```

Is there a way to recover the video by lets say inserting sprop-parameters (SPS/PPS) before every IDR frame?

Is there a way to recover these ts segments? How can I add SPS/PPS before every IDR?

I tried to do that with gstreamer as well but no luck.

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=0.ts ! tsdemux name=demux demux. ! \
 h264parse config-interval=-1 ! mpegtsmux name=mux ! filesink location=0_gstfix.ts demux. ! mux.
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do that with rtph264pay if you have the sprop parameter-sets:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=0.ts ! tsdemux ! rtph264pay ! 'application/x-rtp,encoding-name=H264,sprop-parameter-sets=(string)"your_sprop_parameter_sets_string"' ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! mpegtsmux ! filesink location=0_gstfix.ts
```